# trying to install ruby machine getting this error "operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or unwanted software"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-10-universal

**windows 10.**
I downloaded .exe file form the official [site](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) .

When I run the .exe file it shows the following error :

```
operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or unwanted software
```

I search on internet and get solution turn off **windowsdefender** and try again.

My question is it good to turn off **windowsdefender** and install and why this error is comming ?
 when downloaded the .exe form official site

Comment: the site you mention is completely safe. Though I have been myself coding Rails with Windows for more than a year and switching to Linux / Ubuntu was a real relief. The setup of the different rubies, rails, and some gems installation turned out much simpler with Linux.

Comment: yes linux/ubuntu is awesome.